# Best way to share database for a distributed team

Tags: mysql, content-management-system, distributed, solution

We are a distributed team that works on web projects using PHP and MySQL. We develop a web application with custom code or using CMS like Joomla and Drupal. So far we worked using version control (subversion, currently switching to git) to keep the code base in sync and we share a single MySQL database on a cloud hosting that everyone can reach using a SSH tunnel.

The problem is performance: sometimes the network is slow and it takes forever to refresh a page with a remote database accessed using a SSH tunnel (like 5 minutes to a Drupal refresh). We need to share the same database because we have part of the team that populate the database with data while the rest of the team complete the development and graphics.

I've tried configuring a local MySQL in master/slave with the remote database using the database as master but it really complicates the installation and I didn't see any performance improvements.

Does anyone have any idea to make our configuration work faster or any other solution/organization for this kind of work?

PS. I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821085/what-are-the-best-practices-for-a-small-distributed-team-which-will-work-on-a-dru).

Comment: Is there really any need to have an up-to-the-minute db on the development machines? Is a daily mysqldump frequent enough?

Comment: in some phase of development it's not frequent enough, especially when someone insert content and some glitches on css appears. I've thinked to create a simple script that connect, create a dump and import the dump into the database, but sometimes we really need realtime data

Answer (score 0):

1. Try drupal boost http://drupal.org/project/boost
2. There is also problem in network speed, that can only be solved using better bandwidth or the issue might be because of the shared hosting, In case you are using shared hosting you should try using VPS or Cloud for demo and sort the issue with different tools to find response time , etc . . .

3.http://drupal.org/project/dran

Comment: i know that if the network is slow it's slow but for example i don't know if accessing mysql directly from remote server is anytime faster than using ssh tunnel or if is there any way to speedup mysql sync from one server to another. Boost is a great suggestion but it's a big cache and during development cache are not useful because the code changes often.

Comment: There is a lot mysql performance fine tuning tips, but no idea about making faster over network