# How to best share DB backups among dev teams?

Tags: postgresql, backup, development-environment, sharing

I'm currently on a team that uses Postgres and a few other SQL Server databases. We're in a fairly limited environment and do not have access to major cloud provides like AWS, GCP, etc. As a part of each release cycle, I take a snapshot of production's Postgres DB, store the backup on the company's OneDrive and provide a link to all the developers to download. Our Postgres DB is around 3.5GB using the directory format. Each developer then downloads the backup and restores it locally. As for SQL Server, I've created isolated sandboxed schemas in each SQL Server DB and created a user login that can only access them and is barred from the production schemas. Particularly with Postgres, it's difficult to keep all of the developers in sync, especially since we have different schemas for each release, and teams may make modifications to the schema during their development. **Is there a better way to store and distribute these developer DB snapshots, say, via Git or JFrog Artifactory?**

I've found a very limited number (maybe this isn't a typical issue then) of topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889716/best-way-to-share-database-for-a-distributed-team). A few of the comments suggest using drupal but that's not really an option for my team.

Also, I've seen a lot of posts about production backup solutions. I'm not searching for that; this is purely for managing a distributed database backup across team members for different releases.

**Edit 1:**

Perhaps this should be its own question: It's not only the snapshots each release cycle that are an issue. My team is working on a monolithic application comprised of several submodules. During a given sprint, one team might add 5 new tables to a DB. Members of any one sub-team are often required to transition to other sub-teams mid-sprint, so this can present a challenge if their database doesn't have the same schema updates as the sub-team they're switching to.

Comment: What specifically is the difficulty?  I can imagine several possibilities, but it is hard to solve imaginary problems.

Comment: Why not do it the same way as with MSSQL?

Comment: @jjanes I should probably edit and expand on my question a bit. It's not just the snapshots during release. A lot of times, developers need to make changes to one of the database schemas when we get new project requirements. One subteam may have 5 new tables in their DB needed for a requirement that another team doesn't have. This can create confusion when members switch from one sub-team to another to work on active tasks, which happens frequently mid-sprints.

Comment: Maybe a better option would be centralized test DBs that we overwrite with production each release cycle? That way each dev team doesn't have to share local DB changes with other sub-team. However, it might be a bit chaotic to have several developers modifying the DB schema at once. A lot of new developers are on our team as well, so I'm concerned accidents might happen that affect the overall pace of the project.

Answer (score -1):

you can try git LFS (https://git-lfs.github.com/) after zipping the file. It is for handling large files in git. you can have similar versioning system of git with support for large files.